# javascript uncaught referenceerror function not defined onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automate checking code that will send the value to a php script. I receive error which looks like: function campaignCode is not defined.

HTML

```
<div class="btn" onclick="campaignCode.addCode(event)">Check code</div>
```

javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var campaignCode = (function () {

    function addCode(event) {
    ..
    }
```

What it happens?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And it's not defined ... in the global scope, it's inside the scope of the `document.ready` function, you have to move it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$(document).ready` has its own private scope but `inline` click handlers expects functions to be global(`under the context of window`)

If you have `jQuery` included, why are you dealing with `inline` event attachment.

Use this:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Check code</div>
```